# Functional way to Climb an Association Decision Tree

Tags: associations, code-request

Associations are nice tool to create decision trees. Here is a toy example of how I'm starting to use it:

```
tree=<|True->1
      ,False-> <|
            True-> 2
           ,False-><|
                 True-> 3
                ,False->4
                |>
        |>
|>
```

To have access to it 'leads', I started with this ugly procedural function:

```
getLead[parameters_,tree_]:=Module[{i,temp,len=Length@parameters},
    For[i=1,i<=len,i++,
        temp=tree@@parameters[[;;i]];
        If[Not@AssociationQ[temp],Return[temp]];
    ]/.Null-> $Failed
]
```

Here are some examples:

```
getLead[{True},tree]
getLead[{True,False},tree]
getLead[{False,True},tree]
getLead[{False,False},tree]
getLead[{False,False,False},tree]
```

> ```
> 1
> 1
> 2
> $Failed
> 4
> ```

**Question**

How to make `getLead` in a functional style?

**UPDATE**

This example is more illustrative:

```
tree=<|
   "NoMoney"->"NoMathematica"
  ,"OkMoney"-> <|"NeedsUserInterface"-> "NoMathematica"
                ,"NoUserInterface"-> <|
                                     "NoToFunctionaStyle"-> "NoMathematica"
                                    ,"OkToFunctionaStyle"-> "GoMathematica!!"
                                    |>
              |>
|>;
(*So options are Options*)
{
     {"NoMoney","OkMoney"}
    ,{"NeedsUserInterface","NoUserInterface"}
    ,{"NoToFunctionalStyle","OkToFunctionalStyle"}

};

getLeafFunc[{"NoMoney"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"OkMoney"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"NoMoney","NeedsUserInterface","OkToFunctionaStyle"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"OkMoney","NoUserInterface","OkToFunctionaStyle"},tree]
```

> ```
> NoMathematica   (*Just the first branch is enough*)       
> $Failed         (*Not enough information*)
> NoMathematica   (*First Branch is enough, but no problem to input others*)
> GoMathematica!! (*Example where all branches are needed *)
> ```

Comment: Gah, too sleepy to think clearly.  Why don't you just use e.g. `tree[False, False, False]`?  Is it merely the `$Failed` behavior you seek?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I guess that and that cannot catch `tree[False, False, False, False]`. Otherwise, your suggestion is definitely the way to go.

Comment: @halirutan What do you mean "catch?"  Can we do: `tree[False, False, False, False] /. _Association[___] -> $Failed` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is the obvious solution of recursively calling the access function. This has the advantage that you can easily read the code, because every line clearly says in what situation it is applied and what it does:

```
f[{first_, rest___}, tree_?AssociationQ] := f[{rest}, tree[first]];
f[_, elm_?(Not[AssociationQ[#]] &)] := elm;
f[___] := $Failed;

f[{"NoMoney"}, tree]
f[{"OkMoney"}, tree]
f[{"NoMoney", "NeedsUserInterface", "OkToFunctionaStyle"}, tree]
f[{"OkMoney", "NoUserInterface", "OkToFunctionaStyle"}, tree]
(* "NoMathematica" *)
(* $Failed *)
(* "NoMathematica" *)
(* "GoMathematica!!" *)
```

Or if you don't insist on returning `$Failed` in your third case there is a simple solution using `Fold`. Here, I used `Return` to break out of the `Fold`, but beware of the special situations where `Return` might not leave the scoping construct you think. An alternative is to use `Catch` and `Throw`

```
f2[parms_, tree_] := Fold[
  If[AssociationQ[#1], #1[#2], Return[#1]] &, tree, parms
]
```

Comment: Much more elegant then TakeWhile. +1

Comment: Very cool. You could use the new notation to do `(Not@*AssociationQ)` instead of `(Not[AssociationQ[#]] &)`

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from halirutan's answer but writing for brevity:

```
g[{first_, rest___}, tree_Association] := g[{rest}, tree[first]];
g[_, _Association] = $Failed;
g[_, else_] := else
```

Test:

```
g[{"NoMoney"}, tree]
g[{"OkMoney"}, tree]
g[{"NoMoney", "NeedsUserInterface", "OkToFunctionaStyle"}, tree]
g[{"OkMoney", "NoUserInterface", "OkToFunctionaStyle"}, tree]
```

> ```
> "NoMathematica"
>
> $Failed
>
> "NoMathematica"
>
> "GoMathematica!!"
> ```

---

Slightly shorter still:

```
g[{first_, rest___}, tree_Association] := g[{rest}, tree[first]]; 
g[_, elem_] := elem /. _Association -> $Failed;
```

Comment: +1 Clever as always. But isn't `tree[first]` against yours bracketfobius style? :p

Comment: @Murta Thanks.  I can handle a couple of stacked brackets; the temptation to write this in ~infix~ was there, but I resisted. :^)

Comment: Yes. `{rest}~g~tree@first` would be a little bit strange...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my functional attempt:

```
getLeafFunc[parameters_,tree_]:=Module[{i=0,result},
    TakeWhile[parameters,(i++;AssociationQ[result=tree@@parameters[[;;i]]])&];
    result/._Association:> $Failed
]
```

Applied on our examples, we have:

```
getLeafFunc[{"NoMoney"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"OkMoney"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"NoMoney","NeedsUserInterface","OkToFunctionaStyle"},tree]
getLeafFunc[{"OkMoney","NoUserInterface","OkToFunctionaStyle"},tree]
```

> ```
> "NoMathematica"
> $Failed
> "NoMathematica"
> "GoMathematica!!"
> ```

Just as challenger, It would be cooler if I didn't have to use `i`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it. Each Association contains a question "Q" and each answer which is a key/value in the same Association can be another decision tree. An element is asked repeatedly questions, that should terminate with a decision, ie. an action. If an answer to "Q" doesn't have a corresponding field, a Missing[KeyAbsent,xxx] value is returned.

What I like with this solution is that you don't need to know what's inside the decision tree when you want to take a decision.

It could also be possible to append a list of answers (and even questions) in order to understand what has lead to a given decision

```
climbTree[element_,assoc_Association]:=climbTree[element,assoc[assoc["Q"][element]]];
climbTree[element_,answer_]:=answer (*or answer[element] if you decide that answer should also be a function*)

x=Association["Q"->OddQ,True->Association["Q"->(Mod[#,3]&),0->"0",1->"1"],False->"Hello"];

climbTree[9, x]
climbTree[4, x]
climbTree[5, x]
```

Comment: How would I use your idea to walk over "Mathematica" decision tree?